# Timeout Exception with a serial Barcode reader

Tags: c#, serial-port

I'm having a problem with a HoneyWell Barcode reader.

I have a driver and a config to make it work as a COM serial port (detected with a `SerialPort.GetPortNames()` ).

I manage to open it, and, when I scan a card, the event `DataReceived` event is correctly sent.
But, in this event, when I try a `serialPort.ReadLine();` to get the value stored in the barcode reader's memory, I have a timeout exception.

I can't see why it doesn't work, it's supposed to be pretty basic code. Do you have any hint to help me?

```
public class ScannerHandler
{
    public SerialPort _serialPort;

    public ScannerHandler()
    {
        var serialPortArray = SerialPort.GetPortNames();
        _serialPort = new SerialPort("COM5", 19200, Parity.None, 8, StopBits.One);
        _serialPort.Handshake = Handshake.None;
        _serialPort.DataReceived += new SerialDataReceivedEventHandler(sp_DataReceived);
        _serialPort.ReadTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.WriteTimeout = 500;
        _serialPort.Open();
    }

    void sp_DataReceived(object sender, SerialDataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        var bufferSize = _serialPort.ReadBufferSize;
        var dataBytes = _serialPort.DataBits;
        String data = _serialPort.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance !

Comment: ReadLine is going to wait for a CR/LF to come in - are you sure the device sends that?

Comment: Yes, i set it as a suffix

Comment: Well, what did you pick as a "suffix"?  Does it *actually* match the NewLine setting?  You don't even know if you are getting correct data, start debugging this by using ReadExisting() instead.